# Calculate timestamp when a status is changed and keep it permanent

Tags: calculated-column, timestamp

I've created a calculated field in a custom list which captures the date when the Status field is changed to "**Waiting**".

How can I make this calculated field permanent so it won't be changed in the future when the status is changed to something else?

**Calculated field code:**

```
=IF(Status="Waiting",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated column does not stores any value, it shows value on the fly by calculating.

Instead, You can create a column (datatype=output of calculated field) and fill its value using JavaScript.

Comment: Typically one would use a workflow for this